# Android: Add imageButton on top of a custom keyboard

Tags: android, input, keyboard, ime, custom-keyboard

I have succesfully implemented a custom keyboard. It is working as it should. I want add an `imageButton` on the top of the keyboard as shown in below image so that it always shows above the keyboard whenever keyboard pops up. Can anyone guide me how can I add this image button to my custom keyboard?

[image: Screenshot of keyboard]

Below is the code for the keyboard if anybody would like to see.

**Keyboard.xml** The layout of the keyboard

```
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:keyPreviewLayout ="@layout/preview"
/>
```

The `keyPreviewLayout` is the layout of the short-lived pop-up that shows up whenever a key on the keyboard is pressed.

**qwerty.xml**

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px"  
    android:keyHeight="60dp"
>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="50" android:keyLabel="2"/>
        <Key android:codes="51" android:keyLabel="3"/>
        <Key android:codes="52" android:keyLabel="4"/>
        <Key android:codes="53" android:keyLabel="5"/>
        <Key android:codes="54" android:keyLabel="6"/>
        <Key android:codes="55" android:keyLabel="7"/>
        <Key android:codes="56" android:keyLabel="8"/>
        <Key android:codes="57" android:keyLabel="9"/>
        <Key android:codes="48" android:keyLabel="0" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="113" android:keyLabel="q" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="119" android:keyLabel="w"/>
        <Key android:codes="101" android:keyLabel="e"/>
<!--And so on for all the keys-->
```

**SimpleIME.java** This is the service class for the keyboard

```
public class SimpleIME extends InputMethodService
        implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

    private KeyboardView kv;
    private Keyboard keyboard;

    private boolean caps = false;

    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
        keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
        kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
        kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
        return kv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
//        playClick(primaryCode);
        switch(primaryCode){
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE :
                ic.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
                caps = !caps;
                keyboard.setShifted(caps);
                kv.invalidateAllKeys();
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
                ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
                break;
            default:
                char code = (char)primaryCode;
                if(Character.isLetter(code) && caps){
                    code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
                }
                ic.commitText(String.valueOf(code),1);
        }
    }
```

Place a comment if you vote down.

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted if it has helped you.

Comment: @ user5596252 Did you find any solution for this, if yes please help me

Answer (score 5):

Sure!

1) change `keyboard.xml` as below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivKeyboard"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:src="@drawable/keyboard_icon" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:keyPreviewLayout ="@layout/preview"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

2) In `SimpleIME.java` make a few changes:

```
@Override 
public View onCreateInputView() {

    final View root = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.idee_keyboard_layout, null);

    ImageView ivKeyboard = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.ivRevertKeyboard);

    ivKeyboard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //whatever you want to do...
        }
    });

    kv = (KeyboardView) root.findViewById(R.id.keyboard);

    keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
    kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
    return root;
}
```

Done.

Comment: I tried with solution but did not work getting below error

 Process: com.mykeyboard, PID: 16969
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4915)

Comment: @AshishAgrawal Open a new SO question with your code snippet and provide me the link. The issue you are referring to is about something else entirely.